# how to give format DateTime.Date?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now
dt.Date is created to  31.10.2012 00:00:00 .it is created to  dd.mm.yyyy format but i need dd/mm/yyyy. Can i use:  return new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, 0, 0, 0); it will create to me dd/mm/yyyy solution?Please dont translate String.i need datetime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DateTime` struct doesn't store any formatting information internally. If you want to output the `DateTime` instance as a formatted string, you just need to call [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx) with the proper format string:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var formattedString = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you need more information on exactly which specifiers to use in your format string, check out:

[MSDN - Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy is good for me. But i dont use TOSTRING() method like DateTime.ParseExact...

Comment: @programmerist - I'm not sure I understand the issue then. Are you just trying to create a DateTime instance that represents midnight on a certain date (you can't have a DateTime instance without some time value).

Answer (score 3):

Just the way to convert to string, `DateTime` itself has no format:

```
var result = DateTime.Now.Date
                     .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @programmerist: if you just need datetime how to you know it's different format?

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy is good for me. But i dont use TOSTRING() method like DateTime.ParseExact...

Comment: @programmerist: how do you know it's different format like your question

Answer (score 0):

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var stringDt = dt.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.DateTime` does not have any format. You can view its string representation in format.
Try this

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In you case you can simply use :

```
dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Anyway there al the string format you can use with DateTime : [Here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime`, numeric types and most other types do not store their values in a formatted way. Rather they store their data using a binary representation. If you want to display this data to the user, you must convert it to a string. This conversion involves formatting the data.

```
string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",
                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or

```
Console.WriteLine("Date = {0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
```

`Console.WriteLine` converts the date into a string in order to write it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime structure always has the Date and Time stored in it. If you need to extract the date alone as text you can do the following.

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

This will print the date as in the format as specified by the culture set in the system. The list of standard datetime format strings supported by dotnet framework can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)